# How to call onCreateView() manually

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to call `onCreateView()` **manually** in fragments. Is it possible?

Comment: why do you want do that?

Comment: Post question with sufficient details to get good answers, "if you really wants some good answers"!

Comment: You don't need to call onCreateView manually. It's systme callback, which called by fragment manager to add view to window. If you call it manually you will not able to do add created view to window yourself.

Comment: @Boss ,@Paresh Mayani : Because I am using view pager in my fragment. In here each fragment is automatically call the next fragment. To reslove that i am using setUserVisibleHint in fragment . And also i add some code in setUserVisibleHint true condition . I need to refresh that fragment then only i will get that change.

Answer (score -3):

just write in your fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}
```

Comment: How would overriding the method help them to call it? Either you need to add more details to your answer, or you're not answering this question.